# Iterating through two JSON files to find a match

Tags: python, json, iteration

I have a file of 30k users and a file of 200k reviews.  Each line is a valid JSON structure, but the whole file is not.

For each review, I want to find the corresponding user and note the user's total number of reviews, which is a stored value in the user dictionary.

```
with open('review_file.json') as reviews, open('user_file.json') as users:
    for r in reviews: #r == dict
        review = json.loads(r)
        print "review iteration"
        for s in users:  #s == dict
            print "user iteration"
            user = json.loads(s)
            if user['user_id'] == review['user_id']:
                print review['id']
                print user['user_id']
                print user['num_review']
```

I thought that this would iterate over the users for each review, but it iterates over users for the first review, then only iterates over the review file without looking at the users.

Am I missing something? i would expect it to iterate over the user file for each review. Is there any easier way to handle this? I've been finding that any attempt to abstract the files to a helper class significantly slows this search down.

Answer (score 0):

Because after the first iteration through `reviews`, `users` is exhausted: there's no more to read. You never tell Python to start again from the beginning.

You probably want to do `users.seek(0)` at the start of each iteration of the outer loop.